# How to hide UI without leaving blank space in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xib, uistackview

Default state:

[image]

What i want to do:

[image]

My attempt (i create multiple stackview for each uielement/views, and hide view a or view b based on which radio button selected):

[image]

I want to show different view based on which radio button user selected using xib in Swift.
I tried to create view a and view b inside uistackview in xib, but when i'm hiding view a, it leaves an empty spaces between labels/textfields and button.

How can i show view based on selected radio button and hiding one view without leaving extra white spaces?

Comment: It's pretty straightforward; you just swap which is visible, A or B. Unfortunately you have failed to show _any_ code, so it's hard to guess what you might be doing wrong. And there's no "blank space" in your pictures, so it isn't even clear what the issue looks like.

Comment: okay @matt i have edited the pictures to make it more clear

Comment: Oh, okay. So you are saying that you want to be able to show A or B _or both_, and yet when you are showing just A or just B, the whole stack view should somehow magically shrink. It should be a different size when they are both showing than it is when one of them is showing. Is that right?

Comment: yes that is true, i still don't know how to shrink one of the stackview without leaving extra space/white space.

Comment: Well it all depends on how the stack view itself is configured. A stack view can be self sizing if the constraints upon it permit it to size itself. It must have "room" to grow and shrink, and its contents must be such as to dictate unambiguously how it should do that. So the problem you're describing is easy to solve in the abstract. The details, however, are crucial. We don't know how you're letting the stack view know how big it should be and how big its contents should be.

Comment: All you need is `StackView`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you're trying to do, then it's pretty easy to do it in a rudimentary way. It's just a matter of having the right height constraints on the stack view (none) and its arranged subviews:

[image]

However, for full control, it might be better to dispense with the stack view and take complete charge of the constraints yourself. Remember, a stack view isn't doing anything at all that you can't do by making constraints in code.